# V-for on rendering multiple elements

Tags: html, vue.js, bootstrap-4

Just trying to pick up Vue.js so please be gentle :smiley:

The issue I’m facing is that when i’m binding elements separately on two different columns it everything works, but it messes up my layout. All images load on first row and articles are rendered below.

````
the code =>

```<div class="row no-gutters"> <!-- remove horizontal paddings between columns 4 this row -->

    <div class="col-md-2"  v-for="(post, img) in posts">
      <div class="article-image">
        <img  :src="post.img" />
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-6" v-for="(post, title) in posts" v-bind="post.id">
      <div class="article">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h3>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">21st Dec 17</h6>
            <p class="card-text">{{ post.content }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>```
````

So, I decided to put the v-for on the row class instead and have it loop through image and article one after another, rather than loading all images first and then all the articles.

````
the code =>

```<div class="row no-gutters" v-for="(post, img, title) in posts" v-bind="post.id">
    <div class="col-md-2" v-for="(post, img) in posts">
      <div class="article-image">
        <img  :src="post.img">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" >
      <div class="article">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h3>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">21st Dec 17</h6>
            <p class="card-text">{{ post.content }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>```
````

I’m not sure if I’m failing at declaring it properly, but I’m getting the following error =>

[image]
<sub>(source: [vuejs.org](https://forum.vuejs.org/uploads/default/optimized/2X/8/8660a001b60f804be33b1d8475e79de102329118_1_689x367.png))</sub>

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please add code instead of screenshot of code.

Comment: let me edit that real quick.

Comment: Templates can only have one root element. By using v-for on that root element (referencing the code output by your error) you'd be causing it have more than one, hence why you get the error "cannot use v-for on stateful component root element because it renders multiple elements"

Comment: @KhauriMcClain That would be quite obvious wouldn't it. Do you have a suggestion for me how to achieve the goal of displaying images alongside articles and not break the layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your template in a div

```
<div>
  <div class="col-md-2"  v-for="(post, img) in posts">
    <div class="article-image">
      <img :src="post.img" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6" v-for="(post, title) in posts" v-bind="post.id">
    <div class="article">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h3>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">21st Dec 17</h6>
          <p class="card-text">{{ post.content }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why?

You can only have one root element in your template; `v-for` makes multiple.

Comment: thanks for the direction here. I changed the template a little to adapt to the layout but your solution worked +1

Answer (score 0):

Thats the final template that worked for me...

```
<div>
  <div class="row no-gutters" v-for="(post, img, title) in posts" v-bind="post.id"> <!-- remove horizontal paddings between columns 4 this row -->
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="article-image">
        <img  :src="post.img" />
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="article">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h3>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">21st Dec 17</h6>
            <p class="card-text">{{ post.content }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```